# Show channel name in Playa-dropdown

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

When relating content from several channels in a Pixel and Tonic Playa-field, my client would like to see which channel the articles are from (they might have several articles with similar or same titles...).

There's no native settings for this, but I was wondering if any of you have dared "hack" Playa to display "Entry Title (in channel name)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a timely solution: [Playa Links](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa-links). Here's a blog post with info and images: http://fromtheoutfit.com/blog/playa-links-for-expressionengine

Comment: That looks like it! And no hacking involved. Thanks a bunch, Romans!